# How to save to a JSON file with each key on a different line

Tags: python, json, file

When I save data to a JSON file it will look like this:

```
{'Gri33415': ['Griffiths', 2015, 'Gold', 35, 35000], 'Smi22316': ['Smith', 2016, 'Silver', 3, 7500], 'Mia56213': ['Miah', 2013, 'Platinum', 140, 165000]}
```

How ever I would like each key to be on a different line like this:

```
{"Gri33415": ["Griffiths", 2015, "Gold", 35, 40000],
 "Smi22316": ["Smith", 2016, "Silver", 3, 7500],
 "Mia56213": ["Miah", 2013, "Platinum", 140, 165000]}
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information such as the code attempted to solve the problem and error message, etc.

Comment: If you have a very particular output format, you'll have to assemble the output yourself.

Answer (score 3):

From the official docs: [Pretty printing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

**Edit 1** 
If you only want new lines for keys (e.g. not after every comma) you could solve that via some clever regex trickery. [Live Demo](https://repl.it/HkDo/1)

```
import json
import re

s = json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, sort_keys=True)
s = re.sub(r',\s*"', ',\n"', s)
s = '{\n' + s[1:-1] + '\n}' 

print(s)
```

Comment: Because there are multiple values to a string it puts each element of a new line. @Olian04

Comment: after the second element it creates a new line (I'm not to familiar with regex)

Comment: @eden.c Read up on regex and create your own sollution. Regex is really usefull and not that hard to get a grip of. [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is my favorite regex tool, give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `indent` option when you write out to get pretty print outfile.

```
import json

with open('your_file.json', 'r') as infile:
     data = json.load(infile)

with open('new_json.json', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: It puts each value heald in the key on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and finally find a simple solution.

```
class FirstLevel(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        lines = []
        for k, v in obj.items():
            lines.append(f'{super().encode(k)}: {super().encode(v)}')
        return '{' + ',\n'.join(lines) + '}'

print(
    json.dumps(
        {'Gri33415': ['Griffiths', 2015, 'Gold', 35, 35000], 'Smi22316': ['Smith', 2016, 'Silver', 3, 7500], 'Mia56213': ['Miah', 2013, 'Platinum', 140, 165000]}, 
        cls=FirstLevel)
)
```

The result:

```
{"Gri33415": ["Griffiths", 2015, "Gold", 35, 35000],
"Smi22316": ["Smith", 2016, "Silver", 3, 7500],
"Mia56213": ["Miah", 2013, "Platinum", 140, 165000]}
```

This perfectly suits your need.